# Gas Centrifuge in non-rotating reference frame

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

I'm trying to understand how a gas centrifuge works using a non-rotating reference frame.

If the centrifuge is rotating at a angular velocity $\omega$, then the force required to keep a molecule going around at a radius $r$ is $$F_c=m\omega^2r.$$

Larger masses require a larger force to stay in motion at a particular radius, and so "fall" to the outside of the chamber. The force is provided by the pressure gradient throughout the centrifuge.

I'm confused now about how the isotopes now require an even larger force once they are on the outside of the chamber.

I guess my question is can someone help clarify the ideas above, and why do the heavy isotopes move to a position where the required force on them is greater?

Answer (score 0):

If no force is applied on a body it will move with constant velocity ie in a straight line.

To make a body go along a circular path a centripetal force has to be applied on the body which you have stated to be $F_c=m\omega^2r$.

You make the point that to get a more massive body to move in a circle of radius $r$ requires more force.

So what if the force applied to the body is not sufficient?
The body will have to travel along a path of larger radius tending to travelling along a line which is closer to being straight.
This would mean that the body moves further away from the centre of rotation.

So the bodies with the larger mass require a larger force to keep them rotating at a radius $r$ than bodies with a smaller mass.
If the force is the same the more massive body will move along a path with a greater radius ie "outwards" compared with a less massive body.

Professor Lewin uses the [analogy of a marble in a test tube](https://youtu.be/mWj1ZEQTI8I?t=17m17s) to illustrate the idea that bodies will try and move in straight lines and so move outwards.
Although the marble would start out in an approximately straight line in the end its trajectory would be something like this but all the time going further and further away from the axis of rotation until it hits the bottom of the test tube.

[image]